# D converter: Is there a way to convert D language to java or C++?

Tags: java, d

As D is close to C, I'm wondering if there is a translator out there already.

If not, do you have any other intermediate solutions?

Comment: What's wrong with compiling to native code? Compilers exist for most platforms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rafe.I want to use an ancient D project I got in a very big java project, but I don't want to rewrite the entire D project in java.

Comment: @Dconversor you can try using JNI, but I suspect you're going to have to rewrite the code.

Comment: There's such thing as an *ancient* D project?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark. I'm trying to find such project. Do you have any reference? Was _ancient_ its name? If I find it I will post it here for other future users with the same question.

Comment: @Dconversor He was making a joke. D is a young language, so it surprised him that somebody would talk about a project written in D that was so old it could be called "ancient." Unfortunately, I do not have an answer for you, and I doubt he does either.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. The question is I don't want to rewrite the same thing twice. JNI is not really an option.

Answer (score 5):

There's [TDC](http://dsource.org/projects/tdc), which is an abandoned effort to convert D to C.  There's also [TioPort](http://dsource.org/projects/tioport), which goes in the opposite direction and converts Java to D.  I'm not sure if it works.

Lastly, I *think* LLVM can translate its byte code to (completely unreadable) C code.  [LDC](http://www.dsource.org/projects/ldc) can compile D code using LLVM, and I think (I don't know for sure) that it can output byte code instead of native code.

Comment: Thank you dsimcha. I found [dax](http://dsource.org/projects/dax) which aims to compile D code to Haxe. Haxe, in turn, can compile down to PHP, Flash, JavaScript, NekoVM and C++. Maybe from here a C++ to Java solution can be used.

Answer (score 2):

I'd think your best bet would be to create a thin C language shim on top of the D code, hand build the headers needed to use it and then use something like SWIG to generate the bindings to use the "C" functions from Java.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dsource.org/projects/visuald/wiki/Tour/CppConversion

Running from the console ¶
There is a command line version of this wizard available in the downloads folder: cpp2d.exe

You can pass a config file to the converter that has been saved by the wizard dialog.

cpp2d -config myoptions.c2d [files-specs...]